# Can one schedule a Facebook questi0n?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to schedule when a Facebook question is being posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, for example using PHP. Here is the information about posting the question: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

You could write a PHP file that posts a question and look for a free `cron online service` using Google. Cron services allow you to fetch a specific page/script at a specific date and time, and they can even repeat this. You only have to enter a date and the URL to your script.

Comment: Seems to be possible through the API but not through the FB web interface.